# Chrome timeout Ajax request after 120 seconds?

Tags: php, google-chrome, jquery, lamp

I am not sure if it is a bug or configuration error but I keep getting ajax requests "canceled" at exactly 120 seconds. No http response code given.

The server side is running on a LAMP stack and the php max_execution_time is set to 240 seconds using mod_php5

Oddly enough, if I request the same page without ajax, it won't timeout after 120 seconds.

Early tests shows that firefox does the same thing.

Can anyone help with this bug/annoyance?

Sample code

```
set_timeout_limit(o); 
sleep(1000);
```

Comment: a simple set_timeout_limit(0); sleep(1000); should demonstrate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to add `timeout: xxx` (in ms) to your AJAX call

example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  timeout: 240000,
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I already had your problem!I use set_time_limit(0) but my script stop after 630 Seconds!i put long time on this problem and i figure out that server firewall kill my process!maybe your problem is this too!if you access to your server WHM go to Process manager and take a look at your process! ;)