# .NET and IIS timeout for individual AJAX request

Tags: .net, ajax, iis, timeout

I have an application written with a basic HTML/CSS/Javascript front end, and sending AJAX requests using EXTJS to .NET ASHX handlers.  One particular request can take a long time to execute, and it appears to be getting cut off at exactly 30 seconds.  How do I go about adjusting this timeout value?

Here is what I've tried/discovered.

1. It functions the same in multiple browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox), so
   I assume it is a configuration on the server side.
2. I've looked through the IIS configuration and found a timeout that appears to be
   for session timeouts and it's set to 120 (minutes I presume).
3. The request works fine when a smaller data set is requested, so there
   are no other known programming bugs causing this specific issue.

Comment: Some more digging around in the EXTJS documentation shed light on the problem:  The default timeout for an EXTJS AJAX request is 30 seconds, and can be overridden with the timeout property.   http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/

Comment: Also worth nothing that this stackoverflow question/answer tipped me off.  It relates to JQuery but I figured EXTJS couldn't be much different:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578834/chrome-timeout-ajax-request-after-120-seconds

Comment: In which format you return the data from the server? is it JSON?

Comment: @Brad you should answer your own question to highlight the answer for those who will come here from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more digging around in the EXTJS documentation shed light on the problem: The default timeout for an EXTJS AJAX request is 30 seconds, and can be overridden with the timeout property. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/

Also worth nothing that this stackoverflow question/answer tipped me off. It relates to JQuery but I figured EXTJS couldn't be much different: [Chrome timeout Ajax request after 120 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578834/chrome-timeout-ajax-request-after-120-seconds)

Answer (score 2):

You have to change two things in internet manager.

First:
InetMgr->Default Web Site -> Right side panel -> Advanced Settings -> Connection Limits -> Connection Time-out (Seconds) to be changed to desired number of seconds.

Second:

InetMgr -> Application Pools -> Default App Pool (just select it) -> Right side panel -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model (sub heading) -> Ping Maximum Response time & ping period (both) -> change seconds to desired number of seconds.

Thats all... :)

Let me know if you are having problem still..